# Assembler Error: expression too complex

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

I'm trying to do a simple inline asm command in `C` and compile it with gcc. I want to push the variable `num` to the stack:

```
asm (
    "push %0"
    :          //output
    : "r"(num) //input
    :          //clobber
);
```

The above is generating the error:

```
Error: expression too complex -- `push r3'
```

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#toc3) and I found nothing about the `push` command.

I also tried:

```
asm ( "push %num" ); //Assembler Error: expression too complex -- `push %num'
```

and:

```
asm ( "push %[num]" ); //gcc error: undefined named operand 'num'
```

But none worked.

**edit:**

I'm using this compiler: [arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc](https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries)

Comment: How about `push %%%0` (under the assumption that your assembler requires registers to be prefixed with a % as `push %r3`)?

Comment: It gives: `Error: expression too complex -- push %r3`

Comment: Can you show me what assembly the compiler generates? Pass `-S` to the compiler to generate assembly.

Comment: It might also be useful to see the actual code you wrote. Right now, you've only shown us an incomplete snippet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In ARM assembly, the `push` instruction [is a shorthand for `stmdb`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489e/Babefbce.html). It can push multiple registers at once. Thus, you have to use braces around the operand as it indicates a set of registers:

```
asm("push {%0}" : : "r"(num) : );
```